# HRESULT: 0x80131468 - Download large excel file C#, .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel

On my website, excel download function is working fine for < 10k data rows. If the rows is about 25k, 30k, I receive the following error.

**Unable to create the store directory. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131468)**

And it's working fine on development server.

Comment: A permission problem? See [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242102/a-cause-for-hresult-0x80131468-when-accessing-isolatedstoragebackingstore

Comment: @doctorlove Thx but it doesn't work. I've set full permission for Network Service and I even set full permission for Everyone on this isolatedStorage folder. Still doesn't work. It can download small files though.

Comment: Any chance this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242102/a-cause-for-hresult-0x80131468-when-accessing-isolatedstoragebackingstore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be something to do with the excel export engine do not have permission to temporary store the file to the **IsolatedStorage**
Could you try to check if the user from Application Pool for that Website has permission on write on the follow directory [on the server]
"**C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\Local Settings\Application Data\IsolatedStorage**"

If not, please modify the permission for that user for that folder.

Please correct me if my concept is wrong