# Create User Folders with Installer if not existing

Tags: .net, iis, windows-installer, enterprise-library

I have an application that is being distributed via an installer program. The application uses EnterpriseLibrary.Caching. My problem is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242102/a-cause-for-hresult-0x80131468-when-accessing-isolatedstoragebackingstore). Is there a way that I can get to installer program to create the folders for the IIS user account if they do not already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WIX as your installer authoring tool, you can use CreateFolder element.
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/createfolder.html

Two relevant links:

[Detecting the presence of a directory at install time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937674/wix-detecting-the-presence-of-a-directory-at-install-time)

[Wix - how to prevent overwrite entire directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086719/wix-how-to-prevent-overwrite-entire-directory)

After compile, there will be an entry in CreateFolder table of the MSI.

You can also write a custom action and do the trick in the CA.